# Best way to listen to contract events and trigger a lambda function

Tags: events, server-side, event-handling

I have a database that is updated when lambda functions through the gateway API are triggered. However from my front end when the user is sending a function there is no way to get the event of that sent transaction and update the backend. Because they can also close the browser in the mean time, before the transaction is fully processed.

The Graph can index events, but there is no way for graph to directly invoke my API endpoint for example - upon an event.

Is there such a service that can listen for my contract events and then pass that info over to my API endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new openzeppelin tool "Defender" has a section called "Sentinel", I don't sure this tool helps you, but it "allows you to monitor transactions to a contract by defining conditions on events, functions, transaction parameters"
I prefer to read more about this tool [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/sentinel)

Comment: this one does it, thanks. Also, I would add notify service from Alchemy (Notify API Quickstart)